# Adding a docBase for Virtual Host using the Tomcat Virtual Host Manager

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

In the Tomcat Virtual Host Manager there is an option to add a virtual host with options for:

- Name
- Aliases
- App base
- AutoDeploy
- DeployOnStartup
- DeployXML
- UnpackWARs
- Manager App

However there doesn't appear to be an option to set the docBase for a virtual host as I have done previously when adding them manually in the XML configuration file:

```
<Host name="[my_domain_name]" appBase="webapps">
   <Context path="" docBase="[path_to_my_site]" />
</Host>
```

Is there any way to  add this via the manager, or if not, what would the default docBase end up being?

Thanks.

N.B. I'm using Tomcat 7

Comment: You might wanna move this to Server Fault, Andrew, http://serverfault.com/about

Comment: Good point Adam. I didn't see a "move" option, but I have submitted over there instead. http://serverfault.com/questions/598123/adding-a-docbase-for-virtual-host-using-the-tomcat-virtual-host-manager

Comment: @AdamCameron suggested precisely the same thing when I spotted this!